# Mathematical undergraduate education in Syria

Tags: undergraduate-education

I'd like to learn some things about undergraduate mathematical  education in Syria **EDIT: In particular I'm interested in students 15-16 years old.**

- What are the main differences from the European countries?
- Are there any interesting facts about undergraduate mathematical education in Syria?
- Where could I find (books, articles) information about undergraduate mathematical education in Syria?

I'd like the material to be in English. I know almost nothing about undergraduate education in Syria. What I found most about was about education in general whereas I'd like information about mathematics in specific.

**SECOND EDIT : Any answer regarding countries at war that have immigrants is also acceptable**

Comment: Welcome to matheducators.SE. You might want to specify the languages in which the material can be and what you know already. Have you checked out the Wikipedia page on education in Syria and its sources?

Comment: @Tommi Brander Thanks! I'd like the material to be in English. I know almost nothing about undergratuate education in Syria. What I found most about was about education in general whereas I'd like information about mathmatics in specific.

Comment: You can start by their [ministry of higher education website](https://web.archive.org/web/20100805024617/http://www.mhe.gov.sy/new/index.php?page=show&ex=2&dir=docs&lang=2&ser=1&cat=1176&ref=home)